# ISO 19110 in Geonetwork

Tags: metadata, geonetwork

I am using Geonetwork  for metadata storage and search and from what I have found I got to knoew that it does support the ISO 19110 meant for the feature catalog but I want to know where do we add the feature description in the metadata of geonetwork
Please help me with this as I can not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using geoNetwork 2.10.x or below, maybe this can help you:

https://trac.osgeo.org/geonetwork/wiki/Iso19110Support

It is the development proposal to support feature description on geoNetwork editor using iso19110.